# Microsoft SQL query with digit

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In my table there are rows with a field like the follow:

- IT_0001
- IT_0002
- IT_0003
- IT 0004
- IT 0005

I need to execute a *like query*

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE my_column LIKE '%my_value%';
```

My possible values are:

```
IT 0005

my_value == 'IT_' => OK
my_value == 'IT' => OK
my_value == 'IT ' => OK
my_value == 'IT 0' => No result Expected: 2 rows
```

I've done some tries with a column value: `'A 231234'`
I've tried `'%A 2%'` and I've found correct rows. So, I think that the problem is `0` string in compare value.
What's wrong?

Comment: Why `like '%IT 0%'` will not output 2 rows ? May be you are telling `IT0` ?

Comment: `SELECT 1 WHERE 'IT 0004' LIKE '%IT 0%'` returns `1`. Your query does what you think it does, so the most likely possibility is that your data is not what you think it is. Use things like `LEN` and `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ...)` to see what's really in the columns, in case an invisible character or extra spaces are tripping you up.

Comment: My field is VARCHAR(20)

Comment: are you sure, that `IT 0005` contains a space and not a tab? Furthermore, the `_` is the singlechar wildcard in mssql, so you would also receive a value for somthing like `ITx00005` - is this the intended bahaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about your data
The result is correct

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 'IT 0004'  LIKE '%IT 0%' --returns 1
SELECT 1 WHERE 'IT  0004' LIKE '%IT 0%' --returns nothing
SELECT 1 WHERE 'IT OOO4'  LIKE '%IT 0%' --returns nothing
```

Answer (score -1):

My external database contains double space instead one space, my client rapresentation doesn't show two spaces but just one.

Comment: The data has two spaces and yet that select returns 2 rows?  Not buying.